# Laravel sanctum check if user is authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

How to check if the user is authenticated when using Laravel sanctum?

Example :

Controller :

```
public function testAuth(Request $request)
{ 
     if ($request->user()) {
            return "auth";
      } else {
            return "guest";
      }
}
```

api.php

```
Route::get('testauth', [MyTestController::class, 'testAuth']);
```

this route always returns **guest** even if I pass **token** in headers.

when I add sanctum middleware,  route return **auth**

api.php

```
Route::get('testauth', [MyTestController::class, 'testAuth'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

but I don't want that , I want to check if the user is authenticated in the controller without using middleware

Comment: Auth::check() is not working when using sanctum

Comment: Why you do not want to use **middleware**? You can share any special case so we can help.

Comment: You can just try to get the user with Auth::user().

Answer (score 4):

Try this following code will help you.....You can use user('sanctum') instead of user()

```
public function testAuth(Request $request)
{ 
     if ($request->user('sanctum')) {
            return "auth";
      } else {
            return "guest";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use `$request->user('sanctum')` to access the details of the authenticated user. However, I found the solution below to be more reliable:

**Optional solution**

Create a custom middleware from `app\Http\Middleware` you can name it anything, let's say `CustomSanctumAuth.php`, and add the following code:

```
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class CustomSanctumAuth
    {
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        {
            if ($request->bearerToken()) {
                Auth::setUser(Auth::guard('sanctum')->user());
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

From this file `app/Http/Kernel.php` add `guard:sanctum` to the array in the `api` key in `$middlewareGroups` array as seen below:

```
    'api' => [
        'guard:sanctum',
        // others ...
    ],
```

In `$middlewareAliases` (laravel >=10) or `$routeMiddleware` (laravel < 10)  add  `'guard' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomSanctumAuth::class,` as seen below:

```
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'guard' => \App\Http\Middleware\OptionalAuthSanctum::class,
        // others ...
    ];
```

**Note**: Make sure to include the authorization bearer token in the HTTP header

Finally, you will be able to access the authenticated user in either method:

```
public function yourController(Request $request) {
    // return $request->user('sanctum');
    // return auth()->user();
    return Auth::user();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return auth('sanctum')->check() ? "Auth" : "Guest";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question, or did you mean to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71831759/edit) with this information? Please make sure you're using the right sections.

Comment: Maybe he just tried to answer his own question after solve it.. I tried it and the code works fine [like the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71832328/9039350) above

Answer (score 0):

first attach **auth** middleware with **sanctum** guard like this to route

```
Route::get('/somepage', 'SomeController@MyMethod')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Then inside route closure/controller action access it with

```
auth()->user()
```

as usual

*authorization http header must hold your bearer token*